# How can I setup a react project in local with files I downloaded from server?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to setup already created react app in my local for further updation. I only have files uploaded to the server public_html.

**Directory view**
[image: directory image]

You can view the files in my root folder here.
Is it possible to setup react project like that. If so someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command should work if everything is set up correctly and you have all the requirements installed locally. `npm start`

Comment: The project itself doesn't have any developer files. Those were the deployed files. So all I could do was edit static files.